# Showing a splash image is blank some seconds

Tags: performance, delphi, splash-screen

In my application I have a splash image during connection to database and other initialization . It works fine to show the splash image, but there it is blank of a period.
So,

1. Splash image is loaded and shown a fraction of a second.
2. Splash image got blank 2-3 seconds.
3. Splash image is shown again some seconds.
4. Splash is closed.

Is there a clever thing to just show the image as quick as possible and remove the blank image ?

The code in the DPR-file:

```
Application.Initialize;

SplashForm := TSplashForm.Create(Application);
SplashForm.Show;
// Tried Splash.Update here but no difference.

SplashForm.SetPos(15);
// Init code
SplashForm.SetPos(30);

// More Init code
SplashForm.SetPos(100);

SplashForm.Close;

Application.Run;
```

And the splash unit:

```
procedure TSplashForm.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Action := caFree;
end;

procedure TSplashForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  pbLoading.Properties.Text := 'Loading ' + TClientConfig.Instance.AppTitle + '...';
end;

procedure TSplashForm.SetPos(aPos: Integer);
begin
  pbLoading.Position := aPos;
  UpDate;
end;
```

Regards
Roland

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your SplashForm needs to receive the WM_PAINT message in order to show itself, and that's not going to happen unless the message-pump is working.

Put `Application.ProcessMessages` after `SplashForm.Show`.

Comment: actually Update() will do the same synchronously. message loop already exists at that point, but VCL thread doesnt have a chance to draw already invalidated window.

Comment: Thanks. It sounds right but it make no difference. It seems that something takes long time and clear the splashimage.

Comment: ProcessMessages() does not wait. HandleMessage() does

Comment: @Worm `Application.ProcessMessages` is synchronous. It pumps the queue until it is empty, and **then** returns.

Comment: @Roland, did you add `ProcessMessages` after (or in) the SetPos methods?

Comment: Yes, I or I have an call to Update. But that doesn't matter, read my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's not this obvious, but your code appears to show the splash screen and then immediately close it. What happens if you comment out the line that says `SplashForm.Close`?

Comment: I have simplified the code a bit. There is a call to DatamoduleCreate behind init code. That loads the model and takes some time. I want to close the splash when this is finished.

Comment: @Roland The bit of code you took out was the crucial bit that would have allowed us to solve the problem!!

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand it now. My application use Bold and it takes some seconds to load the model. It is during that time the splash is blank. I managed to decrease that time a bit but I don't want to clutter the internals of Bolds SetFromModel with   Application.ProcessMessages.

I think it is ok as this. But thanks for your comments. it points me in the right direction.

/Roland